# Excel 2010 Protect sheet does not lock check box

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010

I have a excel sheet with package(column)/feature(row) selection matrix. I used check box form control (Developer tab) in individual cell to let customer select what feature goes in what product. All is working fine.

Now I want to lock this sheet for accidental modification.

I tried protect sheet however the check box still open for selection or deselection.

How can I protect check box to get selected or deselected accidentally (password required for modification)?

Sorry not allowed to attach a image here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the checkbox is linked to a cell:

Right click the checkbox > Format Control > Control > Cell link

Have the cell the checkbox refers to locked, do this my changing the protection properties of the cell itself:

Right click in the cell > Protection > untick Locked > press OK

Now protect the worksheet.

This should stop any editing of the checkbox control

Comment: You mean `Tick` Locked and not `UnTick`?

Comment: Cell is locked as I have enabled protect sheet. But the problem is the check box is an object that's placed in the cell. No matter cell is locked or unlocked, check box is editable.

Comment: i mean untick, but apparently I misinterpreted the English of the original poster...

Comment: If you have the checkbox linked to Cell and that cell is locked then the checkbox cannot be altered...

Comment: Thanks K_B, how can I have the check box linked to Cell?

Comment: Please read my answer and follow it up, it is explained in the second line:::: Right click the checkbox > Format Control > Control > Cell link

Comment: That works, thanks. However I imagine each check box need to be linked to individual cell that is a daunting task considering I have > 100 cell with check boxes. Do you know a way to link many check boxes at once with cell its copied in? Also after I link a check box with the cell, on changing the state of check box, a value TRUE or FALSE appear in the cell, why is that (I just want simple check box without true/false)?

Comment: That is how it works, you use a tool and it comes with its own dimensions and behaviours. You use a checkbox, this is what it does. If you want different behaviour you might want to consider different tools to use. You could also consider using the ActiveX checkbox instead, those will get protected right away once you lock a sheet.

Comment: Probably you are right @K_B. Just wanted to ensure that if there is a way exist I know it with help from kind people like you. If something is not possible obviously we can not stop using the tool (Excel) :). On using ActiveX check box, yes i tried but it also does not do what I want. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: You write a script to to this linking to cells for you in a certain way you will find meaningful, however that could just cost you as much time as do it manually...

Answer (score 0):

format text in cell to have the same text color as the background color and you dont see th etrue or false but it is still there to be used in look ups etc.

Comment: This seems like it should probably be a comment on K_B's answer.